# TableView showing repeated data after some index

Tags: ios

I am using custom table view cell and my table view showing repeated data after index 5 I don't know why it is done When in ipad it shows after index 8 repeated data it may be indexing problem but couldn't find it below is the code
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"item";

```
ItemCell *cell = (ItemCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[ItemCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
NSLog(@"indexpath.row is %d",indexPath.row);

NSString *stre = [grouporphoto objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if([stre isEqualToString:@"Group"]){
    folderimage = YES;
    NSLog(@"here is folder");

    cell.item = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


}
else if([stre isEqualToString:@"Photo"]){
    folderimage = NO;
    NSLog(@"here is Photo");

    cell.item = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


}




return cell;
}
```

Please help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could it be that you never enter the ifs? The `cell.item` would never get updated and that would explain why you get duplicated data (reused cells). Put NSLog outside the ifs and see if it prints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reset all your variables in another else-statement so that when your cell is reused the variables in them aren't.

```
else
{
    cell.item = nil;
}
```

This should fix it for you.

Comment: Thanks Totumus, You were right I used this                          else{
        cell = nil;
        cell = [[[ItemCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the way iOS handles TableViews. As soon as a new cell comes into view (from being out of view i.e. below the bottom of the screen), it will ask for a new one, in which case it will try to reuse a cell that has moved out of the view.

Because of the reuse, not all instance variables are reset on the cell. You need to explicitly change **everything** you want to change. In other words, all pictures, text, labels etc etc that you want potentially different on each cell, set them explicitly each time.